# Let the user pass a user-defined type as sub-class of the parameter class to define a member

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation

The following is some architecture I have designed.
I have a class X that has a variable member Y that is a pointer (or reference, I haven't decided yet) to class A. Class A is an abstract class. The user of X can create his own derived class from A (for example B:A) and pass it to X (probably, in the constructor) which, somehow, will store it in Y.

To make this work, the user should dynamically allocate an object of type B:A and pass it to X. However, can you think of a simpler way, for the user, of doing this without having to call *new*? Ideally, I would like the user to simply create an object of type B:A and pass it. Then, the constructor of X, somehow, would define Y using it (maybe creating a copy of B:A). The problem is that X doesn't know which derived type is passed and what size it is.

I want to create a single constructor to which the user could pass any type derived from A as parameter, and would be converted into a member variable. It should allow the user to create his own type for taking advantage of polymorphism.

```
   class A {...};   // Abstract class (has pure virtual members)

   class B : public A {...};   // Class defined by the user

   class X
   {
   public:
      X(A &param) { /* abc is defined */ }
      A* abc;
   }
```

Some ideas I had:
Could it work a pure virtual copy assignment operator overloading at A? And having a member at B:A that specifies the size of B:A? However I still don't know how to make it work.

How to solve it? Is there maybe a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to specifically pass an object that's not allocated using `new` of a subclass of A to the function?

Comment: "*To make this work, the user should dynamically allocate an object of type `B:A` and pass it to `X`. However, can you think of a simpler way, for the user, of doing this without having to call `new`?*" - polymorphism is not dependent on `new` being used. It simply requires a pointer/reference to the polymorphic object. The caller could create its derived object statically, if it wants to.  Just so long as the object outlives the `X` object that refers to it.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday, I just want to make things easier for the user of X so he cannot have to worry about dynamically allocating B:A.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I know. The thing is that I want to make life easier for the user so he doesn't have to worry if his B:A outlives the X object. That's why I want to somehow save B:A, or a copy of B:A, as a member of X.

Comment: @AnselmoGPP Well, to save the object itself requires ownership transfer, which means dynamic allocation. Otherwise, to make a copy of a polymorphic type, you will have to the virtual clone idiom, which also requires dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that class `X` is going to own `param` after it is passed in, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A { public: virtual ~A () {} };

class B : public A { public: ~B () { std::cout << "B destroyed"; } };

class X
{
public:
    X (std::unique_ptr <A> &param) : m_param (std::move (param))  { }
private:
    std::unique_ptr <A> m_param;
};

int main ()
{
    std::unique_ptr <A> b = std::make_unique <B> ();
    X x (b);
}
```

When [run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q9PSwczW1ituINaO), this code prints `B destroyed`.  Note that, for this to work, `A` must have a virtual destructor.

If ownership of `param` is to be shared with the caller and / or other objects, use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead (but this has more overhead).  Or, as @Remy says, if you can *guarantee* that the lifetime of `param` exceeds that of `x`, you can store a raw pointer (or reference).

---

**Edit:** As per the comments, a better implementation of the constructor of class `X` would be:

```
X (std::unique_ptr <A> &&param) : m_param (std::move (param))  { }
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
X x { std::make_unique <B> (); }
```

This makes it clear that `x` owns the object passed in.

Comment: Using `std::unique_ptr` in this manner, `X x (b);` doesn't convey whether `x` is taking ownership of the `B` object or not. `std::unique_ptr` should almost never be passed around by lvalue reference. So, in this case, `param` should be passed in either 1) by value, requiring the caller to `std::move` it in, or 2) by rvalue reference, thus eliminating the need for `b`.

Comment: `X (std::unique_ptr <A> &param) : m_param (std::move (param))  { }` If you just see this signature, you wouldn't expect `b` to be empty after the the constructor call. Make the parameter an rvalue reference...

Comment: @Remy Answer updated, thank you.

Comment: @fabian Answer updated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> To make this work, the user should dynamically allocate an object of type `B:A` and pass it to `X`. However, can you think of a simpler way, for the user, of doing this without having to call `new`?

Polymorphism is not dependent on `new` being used. It simply requires a pointer/reference to the polymorphic object. The caller could create its derived object statically, if it wants to.  Just so long as the object outlives the `X` object that refers to it.

> Then, the constructor of `X`, somehow, would define `Y` using it

That is not possible.  The `Y` member would have to be statically typed at compile-time, ie as an `A*` pointer or `A&` reference.  Unless `X` is written as a template class, so that the user can then specify the actual derived type being passed in.

> maybe creating a copy of `B:A`

That is possible, but only if `X` is templated, otherwise `A` will have to declare a virtual `clone()` method that all derived classes override to make copy of themselves.

> The problem is that `X` doesn't know which derived type is passed and what size it is.

Polymorphism doesn't need to know that info.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply require the class to implement the copy operation (the `Clone` function below):

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> Clone() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> Clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};

class X
{
public:
   X(A const& param)
      : abc(param.Clone())
   {
   }

   // allow transferring an object stored in a unique_ptr to the object
   template<class T> requires (std::is_base_of_v<A, T>)
   X(std::unique_ptr<T>&& param)
       : abc(std::move(param))
   {}
private:
   std::unique_ptr<A> abc;
};
```

Note that if you restrict the user to transferring the ownership to of the subclass of `A` to `X`, you don't need to `Clone` functionality at all. You you could remove `X::X(A const&)` and `Clone` in this case. The user would still be able to create your object like this:

```
X x = std::make_unique<B>();
X x(std::make_unique<B>()); // alternative syntax for the above
```